# Null cannot be passed through in the argument list

Tags: python, c, overflow, exploit

I am currently working on a homework assignment for binary exploitation.

```
int zerg(char *arg)
{
    char buf[12];
    static int i, sum;

    if (strlen (arg) > 24){ 
       exit(1);
    } 
}
```

I want to create a buffer overflow but the strlen check is not allowing me to do so. So I thought to use \0 to trick strlen to think that I had less than 24.

I used python to put into my argument. My python script looks like this:

```
padding = 'A'*12
n = '\0'
payload = 'BBBB'*100
print padding+n+payload
```

I got this issue:
xargs: WARNING: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed through in the argument list.

How can I get pass the strlen check?

Comment: Your code lacks a closing } and is malformated, could you please fix that?